# How to set FXML "padding" property in one line

Tags: java, javafx, padding, coercion, type-coercion

I would like to define a button's padding the same way as in C# XAML files. Instead of writing things like:

```
<Button fx:id="btn1" ...>
    <padding>
        <Insets top="0" right="5" bottom="10" left="5" />
    </padding>
</Button>

<Button fx:id="btn2" ...>
    <padding>
        <Insets topRightBottomLeft="5" />
    </padding>
</Button>
```

, it would be easier to write:

```
<Button fx:id="btn1" ... padding="0 5 10 5" />
<Button fx:id="btn2" ... padding="5" />
```

I don't know why is there this limitation for the "padding" property. I have seen on the [FXML documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html) that **type coercion** can be done implementing a ***valueOf()*** method for the given type :

```
public static Insets valueOf(String info) {
    // Data retrieval
}
```

But I don't know where to place it, because **Insets** class is locked (JDK). Because this is a static method, I thought that the method could be implemented elsewhere, but launching the application always gives me a coercion error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to coerce 0 5 10 5 to class javafx.geometry.Insets.
```

For the moment, the only solution I have found is to:

- Define a new FXML component called **GButton**, that inherits **Button**
- Define a **Spacing** class that inherits **Insets** and implement a ***valueOf*** method for this class
- Add a "space" property for GButton (instance of **ObjectProperty<Spacing>**) which has the same behaviour as "padding", and define its getter and its setter.

Is there a simple way to define FXML "padding" into the Button markup, without creating a class inherited from Insets?

By the way don't forget to upvote if the question is useful :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I don't know why is there this limitation for the "padding" property. I have seen on the FXML documentation that type coercion can be done implementing a `valueOf()` method for the given type

This would require `Insets` to implement a `static` `valueOf(String)` method. This method does not exist in that type; therefore you cannot simply specify the value via an attribute.

[Introduction to FXML](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#property_setter_elements):

> Additional conversions can be implemented by defining a `static valueOf()` method **on the target type**.

You could use the `style` property to specify the value via CSS though. This is often shorter than assigning an object to a property:

```xml
<Button fx:id="btn1" style="-fx-padding: 0 5 10 5;" .../>
```

For more on the supported properties/syntax, take a look at [the CSS Reference Guide](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, fabian :) CSS styling is a solution but it has limitations too :
* CSS styling is a little bit less performant than direct FXML styling, which is notable when there is a huge HMI
* Is it possible to bind data with that syntax? I believe that CSS style is only applied once, when the GUI is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is old, but hopefully I can provide some insightful information. I had the same problem; unfortunately FXML doesn't have full documentation, but piecing together the initialization model makes it intuitive in my opinion.

In any case, you had the right approach, just didn't quite complete it:

```xml
<padding>
    <Insets top="10" right="20" bottom="30" left="40"/>
</padding>
```

will create a padding equivalent to CSS's `padding: 10 20 30 40`, which of course, you can change (and even use FXML variables I would assume).

In general, though, any class that has `javafx.beans` properties in the proper convention (see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm) for an explanation), you can quite easily create custom components in FXML and assign member values like you can with the `Insets` above.

Hope this helps anyone!